# How do i solve "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' error in webscrapping"

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm new to web scrapping and having an issue with using the .findAll attribute. when I run the code below, it says object has no attribute findAll.

I able to scrap succesfully for first page of website https://books.toscrape.com/ but when i try to scrap second page for testing and it throws "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' " error and tried to scrap all the fifty pages of website as well. The same error is coming. someone Please help to scrap all the 50 pages.

The code to scrap 2nd page

```
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser')

#find all the book titles and their links under h3 tag
books = soup.find_all('h3')

book_extracted = 0

#iterate through the books and extract the information of each book
for book in books:
    book_url = book.find('a')['href'] #grabbing or acessing href attribute of 1st book
    book_response = requests.get(url + book_url) #getting the response of the 1st book link
    book_soup = BeautifulSoup(book_response.content,'html.parser')
    
    
    title = book_soup.find('h1').text #extracting title of the 1st book
    category = book_soup.find('ul',class_='breadcrumb').find_all('a')[2].text.strip() 
    rating = book_soup.find('p',class_='star-rating')['class'][1] 
    price = book_soup.find('p',class_='price_color').text.strip()
    availability = book_soup.find('p',class_='availability').text.strip()
    
    book_extracted += 1
    
    print(f"Title: {title}")
    print(f"Category:{category}")
    print(f"Rating:{rating}")
    print(f"Price:{price}")
    print(f"Availability:{availability}")
    print("***************")
```

The error am getting is

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[80], line 18
     14 book_soup = BeautifulSoup(book_response.content,'html.parser')
     17 title = book_soup.find('h1').text #extracting title of the 1st book
---> 18 category = book_soup.find('ul',class_='breadcrumb').find_all('a')[2].text.strip() #extracting category
     19 rating = book_soup.find('p',class_='star-rating')['class'][1] #having two classes star_rating and rating(three)
     20 price = book_soup.find('p',class_='price_color').text.strip()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

and the code loop to scrap all 50 pages is

```
books_data = []

#loop through all 50 pages
for page_num in range(1,51):
    url = f'https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-{page_num}.html'
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser')
    
    # find all the book titles and their links under h3 tag of the current page
    books = soup.find_all('h3')
    
    for book in books:
        book_url = book.find('a')['href'] #grabbing or acessing href attribute of 1st book
        book_response = requests.get(url + book_url) #getting the response of the 1st book link
        book_soup = BeautifulSoup(book_response.content,'html.parser')
    
        title = book_soup.find('h1').text #extracting title of the 1st book
        category = book_soup.find('ul',class_='breadcrumb').find_all('a')[2].text.strip() 
        rating = book_soup.find('p',class_='star-rating')['class'][1] 
        price = book_soup.find('p',class_='price_color').text.strip()
        availability = book_soup.find('p',class_='availability').text.strip()
    
        #appending the extracted data to the list
        books_data.append([title,category,rating,price,availability])
        print(books_data)
```

The error to scrap all 50 pages is

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[82], line 20
     16 book_soup = BeautifulSoup(book_response.content,'html.parser')
     19 title = book_soup.find('h1').text #extracting title of the 1st book
---> 20 category = book_soup.find('ul',class_='breadcrumb').find_all('a')[2].text.strip() #extracting category
     21 rating = book_soup.find('p',class_='star-rating')['class'][1] #having two classes star_rating and rating(three)
     22 price = book_soup.find('p',class_='price_color').text.strip()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'``
```

Comment: Don't make us guess where the error happens.  Please edit the question abd add the full error traceback message.

Comment: `requests.get(url + book_url)` your url framing logic is wrong fix this it will work

Comment: @deadshot i am following youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yoE5pmotmjU , it works for her perfectly.

Comment: try debugging according your logic url will become `https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-{page_num}.html/{book_url}` this is wrong

Comment: try this one `requests.get(url.replace(f'page-{page_num}.html', book_url))`

Comment: The error happens because `book_soup.find` did not find any such elements.  @deadshot is exactly right here, the problem is your use of URLs.  You need to have a base URL (probably ending in `catalogue`), then you can built the page URLs and the individual BOOK URLs using that.

Comment: @deadshot Yes, I have found the mistake, and now the loop is working perfectly and started scrapping. Thanks. Sorry my bad

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, Sorry my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed three lines here.  One is creating the `baseurl` constant, which has the root URL upon which all the other URLs are based.  Two is to change the `url =` line to build from that.  Three is to change the second `requests.get` call to build a URL from the base.

```
books_data = []
baseurl = 'https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/'

#loop through all 50 pages
for page_num in range(1,51):
    url = baseurl + f'page-{page_num}.html'
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser')
    
    # find all the book titles and their links under h3 tag of the current page
    books = soup.find_all('h3')
    
    for book in books:
        book_url = book.find('a')['href'] #grabbing or acessing href attribute of 1st book
        book_response = requests.get(baseurl + book_url) #getting the response of the 1st book link
        book_soup = BeautifulSoup(book_response.content,'html.parser')
    
        title = book_soup.find('h1').text #extracting title of the 1st book
        category = book_soup.find('ul',class_='breadcrumb').find_all('a')[2].text.strip() 
        rating = book_soup.find('p',class_='star-rating')['class'][1] 
        price = book_soup.find('p',class_='price_color').text.strip()
        availability = book_soup.find('p',class_='availability').text.strip()
    
        #appending the extracted data to the list
        books_data.append([title,category,rating,price,availability])
        print(books_data)
```

This is just how HTML works.  All of the links on this page are "relative" URLs.  They do not start with `http://`.  Instead, they are all relative to the page being displayed.  That means you have to build those URLs from the directory that CONTAINED the page.  You were trying to build the URL from the name of the specific page being displayed.  That's wrong.